# Network issue after reboot (16.04)

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, reboot

We have a server running 16.04 which behaves odd.
After a reboot the server can only be reached in the server network (10.10.100.0/24), ping ssh etc works just fine from another server in the same network. When I try to reach the server from my client network (10.10.200.0/24) it does not respond in any way.

Now when I issue `/etc/init.d/networking restart` it is reachable from both networks.

I tried to work around the problem and add the command above to `/etc/rc.local`, and even triggered a separate script from there which sleeps for 2 min before issuing the command. But it still behaves the same way until I issue the command manually.

Any suggestions / workarounds / etc.? I'd be thankful : )

Comment: try this `sudo systemctl enable networking` and lets see if it stays connected

Comment: @George Thanks for the imput. The command didn't do the trick, but helped me figure out a workaround.

Comment: glad it help resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @George I found a workaround.
I added `nohup systemctl restart networking &` to my `/etc/rc.local` now after booting up it restarts the network properly and I can reach the server from both networks.